# Tmux raspbian installation

Tags: osx, tmux, raspberry-pi

i have installed tmux on my pi (raspbian jessie) it has installed ok but when I ssh from osx command + b + " doesn't work, or any other command for that matter. Do I need to create a config file?

Comment: Have you created a session and attached to it? (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course)

Comment: Looks like I have?  `pi@raspberrypi /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples $ tmux list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  6 04:05:57 2016) [157x72] (attached)`

Comment: see my answer below.  You are using the wrong syntax for the command line.  If this answer solves your problem, please select it a the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type `control-b` followed by the modified key (release the `control` and the `b` before you type the modified key).  The Apple/command key does nothing within a normal terminal session nor does Raspian recognize the key (and the fact that it is pressed is probably not even transmitted over the ssh connection). tmux requires the control key as a modifier unless you change the defaults, changing to command would not likely work and, if it did, could create other problems.

Sorry, I should have realized the problem before but I didn't read your question closely enough, I guess.  You don't type the Apple/command key when you are in a terminal you use the actual "control" key, which should be 2 keys to the left of the Apple/command key.  You do this in any terminal session, even locally, as the Apple/command key remains bound to the Aqua gui (e.g. if you press Command-f from within the terminal you will bring up a gui find box outside the terminal that is part of the Terminal app wrapper to the terminal.  Linux and Unix (including Darwin) systems do not generally recognize the Apple/command key.  In the event you need a meta key, generally you should enable the option key in the terminal settings.